Using Buck-Boost as LED driver
I am trying to use a buck-boost controller like LT8390 as a LED driver. This controller can act as a current controller if the current through sensing resistor connected to (ISP/ISN) can be adjusted. The voltage on the sensing resistor is adjustable by using CTRL voltage.

There is a table and formula that says how these are related:


For instance, if I connect CTRL to 3.3V with a 10-ohm resistor as a sensing resistor, it gives a current of ()=100mV/10-ohm=10 mA

However, I've noticed a drop in my output voltage. Despite using feedback resistors connected to VFB to adjust my output voltage to be 40V, it drops to 20V because it's no longer in voltage controller mode, but rather, operating in current controller mode. I haven't found any formulas that can predict the output voltage in current controller mode.

To summarize my struggle: I don't know how to predict the output voltage when the buck-boost controller is operating in current mode. It's no longer functioning as a voltage controller, which complicates things significantly.
Would you happen to have any insights or suggestions regarding this issue?

You cant have both constant current and constant voltage output at the same time.

In constant current mode the voltage the sum of the forward voltages of the LEDs, give or take a tiny bit depending on the exact current you set the driver to.

@user1850479
I was told that the total voltage required for the LEDs is 36V, but I am unable to generate it.

@Linkyyy
But I read that boost controllers can be used instead of LED drivers. But how can they be used when they cannot generate a constant, definable voltage?

Either you're not in constant current mode or someone told you the wrong LED voltage. Double check which of those is wrong.

@chami, as user points out, there is something wrong about your assumptions. When i look up the nscw100 datasheet it mentions typical 3.6V drop, but that is with 20 mA current, not 10 mA. 3.6V times 7 diodes is 25.2 V at 20 mA. Around 20V drop with a 10 mA constant current seems to be on the low side, but it really depends on how good the spice model is, that youre using

"It's no longer functioning as a voltage controller" and that's a good thing.  With LEDs you want to control the current, and the supply voltage becomes a dependent variable.  LED brightness is actually very close to linear with current (even more than with power, due to inefficiencies that are correlated to voltage and temperature)

@  Linkyyy: Thanks a lot. Your calculation clarified what everyone means.


I haven't found any formulas that can predict the output voltage in current controller mode.


I don't know how to predict the output voltage when the buck-boost controller is operating in current mode.

When a regulator produces a constant current, the voltage across the output terminals is completely determined by the load characteristics. If the load is a resistance, then Ohm's law  can predict the voltage. If the load is a string of LEDs, then the voltage is the sum of the forward voltages of each LED. This voltage is essentially determined by the colour of the LED plus any internal losses.
Driving LEDs with a constant voltage is not recommended. They are current operated devices. So a constant current is applied allowing the voltage to float to that required by the diodes.
The current regulator must be able to allow the required voltage to appear across its terminals. The maximum voltage available is called the compliance voltage. The compliance voltage for a current source is like the current limit for a voltage source.
As indicated in the comments, the voltage across a device cannot be controlled at the same time the current through the device is controlled.
